# Edge case with sampling and reconstruction.

Tags: calculus, signal-processing

I know I had been dabbling around this question before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182750/can-i-get-an-independent-proof-of-a-closed-form-of-these-two-related-infinite-se) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286412/bandlimited-reconstruction-of-sampled-periodic-functions), but does anyone have in their bag of tricks the most simpliest and concise proof that:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, \operatorname{sinc}(t-n) =  \cos(\pi t) $$

where

$$ \operatorname{sinc}(x) \triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} \qquad & x \ne 0 \\
\\
1 & x = 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ ?

I can show that both sides are an even function in $t$ and that both sides have agreement when $t$ is an integer.  But what is the simplest way to show equality for all real $t$ ?

This is something that I want to put together for us Neanderthal electrical engineers.  (and thank you.)

Comment: Does this equality actually hold? Are you sure the series converges (let alone to that specific value)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, @Stelios, but indirectly from the results of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem and comparing the Fourier series of a bandlimited periodic function to the Discrete Fourier Transform.  Sampling in one domain causes periodic extension in the reciprocal domain.  Then think of sampling a continuous-time sinusoid at exactly the Nyquist frequency.  (These are terms familiar to electrical engineers doing digital signal processing.  They have simple definitions.)

Comment: @Stelios, it's just about to turn midnight here.  I'm gonna watch the ball drop and get back to this .

Comment: @Stelios, would you like me to do this with a large number finite sum in MATLAB?  if i give you my electrical engineering "derivation" of this, you won't like how we use the Dirac delta function and what we call a Dirac comb.  electrical engineers play fast and loose with the Dirac impulse function.

Comment: I am an electrical engineer myself :). Engineering books like the ones from Oppenheim or Lapidoth, discuss Fourier transforms and sampling theorem for energy limited signals, which are of practical interest for engineering applications. The case you are considering is indeed an edge case as it concerns a signal that is not energy limited and I am not sure whether $\{sinc(t-n)\},n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is indeed a basis for this type of signals (even if they are bandlimited). The answer by fedja seems to be mathematically rigorous and is characteristic of the type of stuff engineers want to avoid! :)

Comment: I actually think that one possible way of showing this has been given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288672/70664).

Comment: but i never groked that answer, @MattL.

Comment: Okay, but if you trust that proof concerning the value of the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2-n^2}$$ then everything is clear, isn't it?

Comment: That result is also quoted in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778729/70664) as "rather classical".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Should I spell out that answer the way I understand it?

Comment: @MattL., please.

Comment: @Stelios *and is characteristic of the type of stuff engineers want to avoid!* Why? IMHO I used next to nothing above the high school material and a bit of common sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is largely based on [this (very concise) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288672/70664) to a related question of the OP.

Note that for $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ the equality is straightforward to show. The interesting case is when $t$ is not an integer. The derivation below is valid for non-integer real values of $t$.

Using $\cos(x)\sin(y)=\frac12\big[\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y)\big]$ we can write

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\textrm{sinc}(t-n)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(n\pi)\frac{\sin[\pi(t-n)]}{\pi(t-n)}\\&=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t-n}\\&=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\left[\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t-n}+\frac{1}{t+n}\right)\right]\\&=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\left[\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2t}{t^2-n^2}\right]\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Now we need the following result:

$$\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2t}{t^2-n^2}=\pi\cot(\pi t)\tag{2}$$

which can be found [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#A_rigorous_proof_using_Euler%27s_formula_and_L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion), and which can be derived from the well-known infinite product representation of the sinc function

$$\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)\tag{3}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You should be somewhat careful with how you understand the sum but, assuming that you understand $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n$ it as the limit as $N\to\infty$ of $\sum_{-N\le n\le N}(1-\frac{|n|}{N})a_n$ (Cesaro summation, which gives the same result as the usual one when the latter makes sense), you can just write
$$
(-1)^n\rm{sinc}(t-n)=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{-2\pi i n(x+\frac 12)}e^{2\pi i xt}\,dx
$$
so the Cesaro partial sums become $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}K_N(x+\frac 12)e^{2\pi i xt}\,dx$ where $K_N(z)=\sum_{-N}^N(1-\frac{|n|}{N}) e^{-2\pi i nz}$ is the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel). What you want to know now is that $K_N$ is symmetric, non-negative, $1$-periodic, has total integral $1$ over the period and uniformly tends to $0$ outside an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the integers. So, for large $N$, $K_N(x+\frac 12)$ is a function that is nearly $0$ on $(-\frac 12+\delta,\frac 12-\delta)$ for any fixed $\delta>0$ and has integral nearly $\frac 12$ over each of the intervals $[-\frac 12,-\frac 12+\delta]$ and $[\frac 12-\delta,\frac 12]$. When you integrate anything like that against $e^{2\pi i xt}$ over $[-\frac 12,\frac 12]$, you'll get approximately $\frac 12(e^{-\pi it}+e^{\pi i t})=\cos(\pi t)$.

The only non-pedestrian step in this argument is switching from the usual summation to the Cesaro one. You can avoid it but then you'll get the Dirichlet kernel instead and the last passage to the limit will be somewhat less obvious (the kernel will not decay uniformly in the bulk of the interval but instead it will oscillate faster and faster there and you'll end up using something like the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to show that you need to look only at the (small neighborhoods of) endpoints.